# Outlook.com People feature

Tags: outlook.com

I saw you answered a post last year about the fact that outlook integrates Facebook contacts. My problem, I want to delete 3 of the contacts (which are my own) but it won't let me delete them. But I don't know how to delete in Facebook. I don't see that info anywhere. Help!

Answer (score 1):

Strange because it works for me perfectly (in WebApp though, not in Windows 8 App):

[image: scressnshot]

also: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/people/manage-people-contact-list